# Is it possible to set a conditional breakpoint at the end of a function based on what the function is about to return?

Tags: debugging, gdb, return-value

I have a more complicated version of the following:

```
unsigned int foo ();
unsigned int bar ();

unsigned int myFunc () {
  return foo()+bar();
}
```

In my case, `myFunc` is called from lots of places.  In one of the contexts there is something going wrong.  I know from debugging further down what the return value of this function is when things are bad, but unfortunately I don't know what path resulted in this value.

I could add a temporary variable that stored the result of the expression "foo()+bar()" and then add the conditional breakpoint on that value, but I was wondering if it is possible to do in some other way.

I'm working on x86 architecture.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239756/can-i-have-gdb-jump-past-a-throw-statement-at-the-end-of-a-function/1239768#1239768) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267674/inspect-the-return-value-of-a-function-in-gdb/267682#267682) answer I thought I could set a breakpoint at the exact location of the return from the function:

```
gdb> break *$eip
```

And then add a conditional breakpoint based on the $eax register, but at least in my tests here the return is not in this register.

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do this without a disassembly listing. If true, your first step should be to run the compiler with (can't remember the flag right now, -s?). But I have to ask: is a temporary variable really that bad? Yes, you have a memory store/retrieve, but an optimizer should remove even that. Oh yeah, what's your optimization level? For debugging it should be very low.

Comment: In the real situation, the function in question is a template using some boost constructs.  It's called form several places, so it's actually faster to add the breakpoing and repeatidly to "finish" until I see the value I'm looking for.  I was hoping I could "automate" this though.  Regarding optimisation, it should be off completely: -O0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with previous commenter that this is probably something you don't want to do, but for me, setting a conditional breakpoint at the last instruction on $eax (or $rax if you are on 64-bit x86) works just fine.

For the code

```
unsigned int foo(void) { return 1; }
unsigned int bar(void) { return 4; }
unsigned int myFunc(void) { return foo()+bar(); }
```

using gdb ..

```
(gdb) disass myFunc
Dump of assembler code for function myFunc:
0x080483d8 <myFunc+0>:  push   %ebp
0x080483d9 <myFunc+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080483db <myFunc+3>:  push   %ebx
0x080483dc <myFunc+4>:  call   0x80483c4 <foo>
0x080483e1 <myFunc+9>:  mov    %eax,%ebx
0x080483e3 <myFunc+11>: call   0x80483ce <bar>
0x080483e8 <myFunc+16>: lea    (%ebx,%eax,1),%eax
0x080483eb <myFunc+19>: pop    %ebx
0x080483ec <myFunc+20>: pop    %ebp
0x080483ed <myFunc+21>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *0x080483ed if $eax==5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ed
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/x 
Breakpoint 1, 0x080483ed in myFunc ()
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get whether you're compiling from the command line or not, but from within Visual Studio, once you set your breakpoint, right-click it and click the "Condition..." option for a dialog to appear to let you edit the condition for your breakpoint to break.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In my case I'm on linux and I'm using g++/gdb.  However, having said that this is not about adding conditional breakpoints, it's about adding a condition for something that doesn't have a representation as a variable in your program.  Does VS allow you to refer to the value that will be returned even if you don't actually have a named variable for it?

Comment: I guess that you may break depending on the result returned by a function, so no variable are yet known, if I understand correctly. However, I don't know much about Linux programming. I wish I could be of better help.